# Android keyboard opens then immediately closes when input field is selected on wordpress website

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery, wordpress

I'm using the PremiumPress theme found here: https://cm10.premiummod.com/?design=cm_style2b

If you open this link in Chrome on Android and click Filters, Keyword Filter then tap on the text field, the on-screen keyboard appears for a second then disappears and closes the sub-menu.

I cannot work out why this happens as it's only on this theme. I've compared it to other themes and I don't see any differences. I'm assuming the issue is with JS, which is beyond my understanding.

You can find a recording of the behavior here: https://gfycat.com/lightheartedsillyarrowana

The site works fine on desktop and even emulating a mobile phone in Chrome on desktop works because of course the on-screen keyboard is not used.

Does anyone have an idea what is causing this?

This is the log from com.google.android.inputmethod.latin when tapping on the input text field:

```
2020-12-01 14:44:12.962 1402-1402/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin W/SessionManager: SessionManager.beginSession():53 Try to begin an already begun session [INPUT_SESSION], end it first
2020-12-01 14:44:13.060 1402-1402/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/KeyboardViewUtil: KeyboardViewUtil.getKeyboardHeightRatio():128 systemKeyboardHeightRatio:1.000000; userKeyboardHeightRatio:1.000000.
2020-12-01 14:44:13.069 1402-1402/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/AndroidIME: AbstractIme.onActivate():84 LatinIme.onActivate() : EditorInfo = Package = com.android.chrome : Type = Text : Learning = Enable : Suggestion = Hide : AutoCorrection = Enable : Microphone = Show : NoPersonalizedLearning = Disable : AutoStartVoiceInput = Disable, IncognitoMode = false
2020-12-01 14:44:13.075 1402-1402/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/Delight5Facilitator: Delight5Facilitator.initializeForIme():561 initializeForIme() : Locale = [en_US], layout = qwerty
2020-12-01 14:44:13.080 1402-1402/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/VoiceInputManagerWrapper: VoiceInputManagerWrapper.cancelShutdown():55 cancelShutdown()
2020-12-01 14:44:13.080 1402-1402/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/VoiceInputManagerWrapper: VoiceInputManagerWrapper.syncLanguagePacks():67 syncLanguagePacks()
2020-12-01 14:44:13.158 1402-22825/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/SpeechFactory: SpeechRecognitionFactory.maybeScheduleAutoPackDownloadForFallback():160 maybeScheduleAutoPackDownloadForFallback()
2020-12-01 14:44:13.165 1402-22825/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/FallbackOnDeviceRecognitionProvider: FallbackOnDeviceRecognitionProvider.maybeScheduleAutoPackDownload():197 maybeScheduleAutoPackDownload() for language tag en-US
2020-12-01 14:44:13.178 1402-1402/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/KeyboardWrapper: KeyboardWrapper.consumeEvent():264 Skip consuming an event as current keyboard is deactivated (state=0, keyboard existence=true)
2020-12-01 14:44:13.227 1402-1416/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/putmethod.lati: The stack is not large enough for a start_depth of 0.
2020-12-01 14:44:13.228 1402-1416/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/StudioTransport: JVMTI error: 103(JVMTI_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT) 
2020-12-01 14:44:13.234 1402-1416/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/putmethod.lati: The stack is not large enough for a start_depth of 0.
2020-12-01 14:44:13.236 1402-1416/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/StudioTransport: JVMTI error: 103(JVMTI_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT) 
2020-12-01 14:44:13.652 1402-1416/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/putmethod.lati: The stack is not large enough for a start_depth of 0.
2020-12-01 14:44:13.652 1402-1416/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/StudioTransport: JVMTI error: 103(JVMTI_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT) 
2020-12-01 14:44:13.743 1402-1402/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin W/KeyboardModeManager: KeyboardModeManager.setInputView():302 setInputView() : inputView = com.google.android.apps.inputmethod.libs.framework.core.InputView{8edc646 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-1080,2022}
2020-12-01 14:44:13.748 1402-1402/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/ConversationToQueryExtension: ConversationToQueryExtension.isEnabledForHostApp():252 Conv2Query not enabled due to current app [com.android.chrome] not in whitelist
2020-12-01 14:44:13.749 1402-1402/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/ConversationToQueryExtension: ConversationToQueryExtension.onActivate():162 onActivate() : Disabled by unsupported host app
2020-12-01 14:44:13.756 1402-1402/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/VoiceImeExtension: VoiceImeExtension.shouldStartVoiceInputAutomatically():336 No private IME option set to start voice input.
2020-12-01 14:44:13.785 1402-1402/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/Choreographer: Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2020-12-01 14:44:14.091 1402-1693/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1089ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=4412204835893, Vsync=4413004835861, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=4413008185500, AnimationStart=4413008595100, PerformTraversalsStart=4413008703100, DrawStart=4413135255800, SyncQueued=4413146259300, SyncStart=4413164133600, IssueDrawCommandsStart=4413164553200, SwapBuffers=4413281966100, FrameCompleted=4413311856500, DequeueBufferDuration=455200, QueueBufferDuration=1680200, GpuCompleted=0, 
2020-12-01 14:44:14.116 1402-1416/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/putmethod.lati: The stack is not large enough for a start_depth of 0.
2020-12-01 14:44:14.116 1402-1416/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/StudioTransport: JVMTI error: 103(JVMTI_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT) 
2020-12-01 14:44:14.229 1402-1416/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/putmethod.lati: The stack is not large enough for a start_depth of 0.
2020-12-01 14:44:14.229 1402-1416/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin E/StudioTransport: JVMTI error: 103(JVMTI_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT) 
2020-12-01 14:44:14.625 1402-1402/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin W/TooltipLifecycleManager: TooltipLifecycleManager.dismissTooltip():130 dismissTooltip(): tooltip with id inline_suggestion_tooltip not found in tooltipManager.
2020-12-01 14:44:14.697 1402-1402/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin W/TooltipLifecycleManager: TooltipLifecycleManager.dismissTooltip():130 dismissTooltip(): tooltip with id inline_suggestion_tooltip not found in tooltipManager.
2020-12-01 14:44:14.840 1402-1402/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/KeyboardWrapper: KeyboardWrapper.consumeEvent():264 Skip consuming an event as current keyboard is deactivated (state=0, keyboard existence=true)
2020-12-01 14:44:14.844 1402-1402/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/VoiceInputManagerWrapper: VoiceInputManagerWrapper.shutdown():77 shutdown()
2020-12-01 14:44:14.896 1402-1402/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin I/AndroidIME: AbstractIme.onDeactivate():161 LatinIme.onDeactivate()
2020-12-01 14:44:15.058 1402-1402/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin W/SessionManager: SessionManager.beginSession():53 Try to begin an already begun session [INPUT_SESSION], end it first
```